# Swift derived property KVO not working issue

Tags: swift, cocoa, key-value-observing

I am trying to implement a `NSCollectionViewItem` class which provides a read-only property derived from `representedObject`, the simplified code looks like this

```
class PersonItem : NSCollectionViewItem {
   var fullName:String! {
        get {
            if let obj = representedObject as? Person {
                return "\(obj.firstName) \(obj.lastName)"
            }
            return "none"
        }
    }
}
```

Surely I can get the value by simply something like

```
person.fullName
```

However, the reason I am providing this property is that I want to bind it to my UI in xib file. The KVO seems only works for changes of `representedObject`, but if the value is from this `fullName` property, it simply doesn't work. I noticed there is a class method

`keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey`

for notifying changes for derived properties, but I cannot override it in my Swift class. It seems this method is not provided there, it says not found, even the class inherits from `NSCollectionViewItem`.

So, the question is how to make the KVO also works for this `fullName` property?

Comment: Try adding dynamic keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things: first, as sunshine mentioned in a comment, you need to mark your property with the `dynamic` keyword for it to be accessible using Key-Value Coding, which is a prerequisite for Key-Value Observing.

Second, `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey()` is a class method. So, to override it, you'd have to use:

```
override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey(_ key: String) -> Set<String> {
    // ...
}
```

Third, however, don't do that. From the documentation for `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey()`:

> The default implementation of this method searches the receiving class for a method whose name matches the pattern `+keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Key>`, and returns the result of invoking that method if it is found.

So, the better choice would be to implement:

```
dynamic class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingFullName() -> Set<String> {
    return ["representedObject.firstName", "representedObject.lastName"]
}
```

That method needs to by `dynamic`, too, because it is looked up by name.

Comment: Fourth thing is that

> ... the classes of the UIKit framework generally do not support KVO ...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html